# SUMIFS type function on Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with employees and hours worked on each date of the period as follows:

| Employee | Clock in | Total hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/07/2021 | 5.5 |
| B | 01/07/2021 | 7.2 |
| C | 01/07/2021 | 4.7 |
| A | 01/07/2021 | 2.1 |
| B | 02/07/2021 | 6.5 |
| C | 02/07/2021 | 5.9 |

Some of the employees work split shifts, and I need to know their total hours worked for each day of the two week period (in order to see if they're over the threshold for overtime), so what I need to do is output a dataframe which shows each employee, and each day, but with their total hours worked for that day. I figure this is some version of looping through each employee, with a nested loop within that, looping through each day and totalling the hours, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the result I need.

This is easy to achieve in Excel, using a SUMIFs function or pivot table, but I'm on a drive to automate some of my manual spreadsheeting whilst improving my Python skills.

I tried to work along those lines, but that appears to loop through each employee multiple times and return the total of everyone's hours for the period, so it's clearly very wrong...

```
import pandas as pd

# data is the dataframe laid out in the above format

names_list = data['Employee'].unique()
employee_count = len(names_list)

for row in data.index:
    for name in names_list:
        for date in dates_list:
            total_hours = data['Total hours'].sum()
            print(f'{name}, {date}, {total_hours}')
```

Comment: Do you mean `df.groupby(["Employee", "Clock in"])["Total hours"].sum()`?

Comment: Perfect. I also used unstack(). Will edit above with the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution:

```
summed_data = data.groupby(['Clock in', 'Employee'])['Total hours'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
summed_data.head()
```